# Elasticsearch returning spurious matches in search results using cURL from command line

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I've been having quite a bit of trouble getting Elasticsearch 1.7.x to play ball - I've been trying to implement a bug fix and some extra scoring functionality with a search that already uses it, but often contains irrelevant results.

I therefore decided to go back to absolute basics, with the following query:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/merchantv2/_search '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "businessName": "test"
        }
    }
}'
```

I have only two documents in my index at the moment. One with `businessName` set to "Test Merchant", which I'd expect the above query to match, and one with businessName set to "", which I'd expect it *not* to match.

However, the result of running that precise query is the following:

```
{  
   "took":1,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":2,
      "max_score":1.0,
      "hits":[  
         {  
            "_index":"merchantv2",
            "_type":"searchablemerchant",
            "_id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{  
               "merchantGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
               "v1MerchantId":0,
               "locatorId":"0",
               "address":{  
                  "addressGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                  "postCodeDetails":{  
                     "postCodeKey":0,
                     "postalDistrict":{  
                        "postalDistrictKey":0,
                        "postalDistrict":""
                     },
                     "postalLocation":"0",
                     "latitude":0.0,
                     "longitude":0.0,
                     "townName":"None",
                     "countyKey":0,
                     "countryKey":0,
                     "postCode":{  
                        "postCodeKey":0,
                        "postCode":" 0"
                     }
                  },
                  "county":{  
                     "countyKey":0,
                     "countyName":"",
                     "countryKey":0,
                     "recStatus":3,
                     "countryKeyValue":0
                  },
                  "countryKey":0,
                  "addressTypeKey":0,
                  "updateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "createdDate":"2016-01-07T19:46:28.4463+00:00"
               },
               "searchableAddress":" 0",
               "searchablePhone":"",
               "searchableFax":"",
               "businessName":"",
               "contacts":[  

               ],
               "opportunities":[  
                  {  
                     "opportunityGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                     "merchantGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                     "location":{  
                        "locationGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "tradingAddress":{  
                           "verified":false,
                           "addressGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                           "postCodeDetails":{  
                              "postCodeKey":0,
                              "postalDistrict":{  
                                 "postalDistrictKey":0,
                                 "postalDistrict":""
                              },
                              "postalLocation":"0",
                              "latitude":0.0,
                              "longitude":0.0,
                              "townName":"None",
                              "countyKey":0,
                              "countryKey":0,
                              "postCode":{  
                                 "postCodeKey":0,
                                 "postCode":" 0"
                              }
                           },
                           "county":{  
                              "countyKey":0,
                              "countyName":"",
                              "countryKey":0,
                              "recStatus":3,
                              "countryKeyValue":0
                           },
                           "countryKey":0,
                           "addressTypeKey":0,
                           "updateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                           "createdDate":"2016-01-07T19:46:28.4463+00:00"
                        }
                     },
                     "opportunityLocatorId":"000000"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            "_index":"merchantv2",
            "_type":"searchablemerchant",
            "_id":"5f55fe61-ca65-e411-93f3-0cc47a07ef4a",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{  
               "merchantGuid":"5f55fe61-ca65-e411-93f3-0cc47a07ef4a",
               "locatorId":"PM227Z02",
               "address":{  
                  "addressGuid":"5c55fe61-ca65-e411-93f3-0cc47a07ef4a",
                  "houseNumber":"242",
                  "streetName":"Acklam Road",
                  "houseName":"",
                  "flatAptSuite":"",
                  "townName":"London",
                  "postCodeDetails":{  
                     "postCodeKey":1,
                     "postalDistrict":{  
                        "postalDistrictKey":2782,
                        "postalDistrict":"W10"
                     },
                     "postalLocation":"5JJ",
                     "latitude":51.52094651,
                     "longitude":-0.20149990,
                     "townName":"London",
                     "countyKey":0,
                     "countryKey":224,
                     "postCode":{  
                        "postCodeKey":1,
                        "postCode":"W10 5JJ"
                     }
                  },
                  "county":{  
                     "countyKey":626,
                     "countyName":"Kensington And Chelsea",
                     "countryKey":224,
                     "recStatus":1,
                     "countryKeyValue":224
                  },
                  "countryKey":224,
                  "addressTypeKey":0,
                  "updateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "createdDate":"2016-01-07T19:46:28.4653+00:00"
               },
               "searchableAddress":"242 Acklam Road, London, Kensington And Chelsea, W10 5JJ",
               "searchablePhone":"+44 2031954484",
               "searchableFax":"",
               "businessName":"Test Merchant",
               "contacts":[  

               ],
               "opportunities":[  

               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Note the fact that there are two hits and that one of them is the document with the empty `businessName`.

WT...?

Could somebody explain to me why this is happening, please?

(I've used the first `match` sample query under *Structure of a Query Clause* at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/query-dsl-intro.html as a template.)

**EDIT: Totally my bad (I'm pleased to say)**

Nothing to do with Elasticsearch. I was copying and pasting `curl` commands around all over the place, then over-edited this one. The missing -d flag meant the query document wasn't submitted to Elasticsearch, effectively turning my command into:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/merchantv2/_search
```

This, of course, returned all documents in the index. #facepalm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a search payload with curl, you need to use the `-d` command-line switch otherwise you're just hitting the `_search` endpoint without constraints:

```
                                               this is missing
                                                     |
                                                     V
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/merchantv2/_search -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "businessName": "test"
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Ah sheeit. Thanks. I'd pasted/executed quite a few curls and just missed it. Ta!